# How to add a query to a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 3 tables.
For simplicity I changed them to these sample tables.

table1: CorporateActionSmmary

```
RATE  Quantity  ProductID
--------------------------
56        0        1487
30        0        1871
40        0        8750
```

table2# ProductMaster

```
RATEGROSS  ISIN      ProductID
--------------------------
60         JP0001     1487
33         JP0002     1871
45         JP0003     8750
```

table3# OpenPosition

```
Quantity        ProductID
-------------------
5              1487
1              1487
5              1487
3              1871
2              1871
4              8750
2              8750
7              8750
3              8750
```

First I need to add ISIN from table2 to table1
table1: CorporateActionSmmary

```
RATE  Quantity  ProductID      ISIN
-------------------------------------
56        0        1487       JP0001 
30        0        1871       JP0002 
40        0        8750       JP0003
```

So, I used this code

```
SELECT [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary].*, [dbo].[ProductMaster].[ISIN]
FROM [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary] JOIN [dbo].[ProductMaster] ON CorporateActionSummary.ProductID = ProductMaster.ProductID
```

Now as you can see the Quantity is missing in Table1 so I have to add-up all the quantities in Table3 for each product ID and add to Table1(as a new column or over-write the Quntity column)

I think I can get the sum of each ProductID's Quantity by the following code, But how can I add it to Table1 that already has ISIN column

```
SELECT SUM(Qantity),ProductID
FROM [dbo].[OpenPositions]
```

I am super new to SQL, please explain in detail if it is possible, thank you

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: `first I need t add ISIN from table2 to table1` That is not exactly what you do or what you wanted. It is the wrong concept or understanding. You want to retrieve some information from the database, you write a `SELECT` query. The query may retrieve from multiple columns from multiple tables. You specify how one table is `JOIN` to another in the `ON` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there.. you just need to use the same logic to join to the product master table. However, since you need the total of quantity, you need to group by the other columns you select (but not aggregate).

The query will be something like this :

```
SELECT 
[dbo].[CorporateActionSummary].ProductID
, [dbo].[ProductMaster].[ISIN]
,sum([OpenPosition].Quantity) as quantity

FROM [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary] 

JOIN [dbo].[ProductMaster] 
ON CorporateActionSummary.ProductID = ProductMaster.ProductID

JOIN [dbo].[OpenPosition] 
ON CorporateActionSummary.ProductID = OpenPosition.ProductID


group by 

[dbo].[CorporateActionSummary].ProductID
, [dbo].[ProductMaster].[ISIN]
```

if you want to add more columns to your select, then you need to group by those colums as well

Comment: Your code worked for [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary].ProductID   thank you. but why I get an error with [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary].*  I need to have all of the column from there.

Comment: Please read my comment at the end of my answer. select * is never advisable. Select only the columns you actually need. If you need everything, specify the columns explicitly. so if you add a colum in the select, you need to add it to the grouping as well (group by )

Answer (score 2):

you can sum the quantities and then join with your query like so:

```
SELECT CA.*, PM.[ISIN],CA.Quantity
FROM [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary] CA
JOIN [dbo].[ProductMaster] PM
  ON CA.ProductID = PM.ProductID
JOIN (
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Qantity) Quantity
FROM [dbo].[OpenPositions]
GROUP BY ProductID
) OO
 on OO.ProductID = CA.ProductID
```

Comment: I don't think I understand you. CA is [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary] ?  so what this line means ? --> FROM [dbo].[CorporateActionSummary] CA

Comment: @Ksaman I'm giving the tables an alias ,and using that alias instead of actual table name everywhere in the query for better readability .